# How to find percentage of two inputs dynamically using Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have these input to find discount for an Item. Below I will explain should work

- When amount is inserted in first input the total should show the negative of that value
- When % is selected from dropdown the amount entered in first input be showed as negative in total and the second input will be 0 initially if no value is inserted
- For example first input value is 10 and second input value is 100, the total should show -10

```js
$(document).on('change', '.amountOrPercent', function() {
  var amountOrPercent = $(this).find(":selected").val();
  if (amountOrPercent == 'amount') {
    $(this).closest('.divForCalculation').find('.extraForPercentage').remove();
 
  } else if (amountOrPercent == 'percentage') {
    $(this).closest('.divForCalculation').append(`<div class="extraForPercentage" style="flex: 1">
                <span class="mr-2 pt-2">Of</span>
                <div style="display: inline;">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="0" required style="display: inline; width: 60%;" value="">
                </div>
            </div>
            `);
  }
});


$(document).on("change keyup keypress", ".discountAmount", function() {
  var discountAmount = 0;
  var discountPercentage = 0;
  discountAmount = $(this).val();
  $('.invoiceItemAmount').val(discountAmount);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mr-2 divForCalculation">
  <div style="display: flex" class="calculation-container">
    <div class="mr-2">
      <div class="input-group my-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control discountAmount" name="snpid" placeholder="0">
        <select id="lunch" class="form-control amountOrPercent" style="padding: 4px;">
          <option value="amount">$</option>
          <option value="percentage">%</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<br><br><br>
<label>Total<label>
<input type="text" class="invoiceItemAmount" Placeholder="0" value="">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the below code I have updated, your question is little bit confusing, but I hope as per my understanding you might get help with below fix.

```js
  $(document).on('change', '.amountOrPercent', function() {
  var amountOrPercent = $(this).find(":selected").val();
  if (amountOrPercent == 'amount') {
    $(this).closest('.divForCalculation').find('.extraForPercentage').remove();
    $(this).closest('.divForCalculation').find('.amountOrPercent').css('padding', '4px');
    $(this).closest('.divForCalculation').find('.divForCalculation').css('flex', '1');
  } else if (amountOrPercent == 'percentage') {
    $(this).closest('.divForCalculation').find('.divForCalculation').css('flex', '2');
    $(this).closest('.divForCalculation').find('.amountOrPercent').css('padding', '0');
    $(this).closest('.divForCalculation').append('<div class="extraForPercentage" style="flex: 1"><span class="mr-2 pt-2">Of</span><div style="display: inline;"><input type="text" class="form-control totalof" placeholder="0" required style="display: inline; width: 60%;" value=""></div></div>');
  }
});


$(document).on("change keyup keypress", ".discountAmount, .totalof", function() {
  var discountAmount = 0;
  var discountPercentage = 0;
  var totalof=0;
  var result=0;
  discountAmount = $(".discountAmount").val();
  totalof=$(".totalof").val();
  if(totalof==null || totalof==0){
  totalof=0;
  result=-discountAmount;
  }
else
    {  
    result = -parseFloat((parseInt(totalof)/100*parseInt(discountAmount)));
}
    $('.invoiceItemAmount').val(result);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        
    </style>
    <script src="/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mr-2 divForCalculation" style="flex: 1">
  <div style="display: flex" class="calculation-container">
    <div class="mr-2" style="flex: 1">
      <div class="input-group my-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control discountAmount" name="snpid" placeholder="0">
        <select id="lunch" class="form-control amountOrPercent" style="padding: 4px;">
          <option value="amount">$</option>
          <option value="percentage">%</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<br><br><br>
<label>Total<label>
<input type="text" class="invoiceItemAmount" Placeholder="0" value="">
```

Comment: Everything is fine, but the 10 percent of 30 gives me 33.33, the actual result is 3

Comment: I have just changed the formula and updated the snippet, check it if it is o.k with that.

Comment: What if I have multiple .discountAmount and .totalof classes?

Comment: It is getting previous input value invase of two rows

Comment: it depends, just update your example in snippet and will provide you the solution.

Comment: I will add separate question